# Centering title of a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, dcolumn

I have made the following table. I have two issues with it:

1. The yellow text acts as a "title"/"caption" for that panel. I'd like to center it relative to the entire table. Using `c` instead of `l` doesn't center it though and I believe the issue is that I am have made it as a `multitable`. Is there a better way to write this "title" that allows me to center it?
2. Is it possile to shorten the rule below the table caption, e.g. by removing the part circled in red?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newlength\summaryTblPanelSep
\setlength\summaryTblPanelSep{-1ex}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
    
    \begin{document}
   

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{D{.}{.}{-2}}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Title}\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
&\alpha &\beta\\\midrule \\ [-2ex]

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{This is a very long, long, long, long, long, long, caption for this panel}}\\
\midrule
This is config a  &1.11  &2.22\\
This is config b  &-1.11  &-2.22\\
  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 

\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{c}` instead of `\multicolumn{2}{l}` centers teh bold text with respect to all three columns.

Comment: Unrelated, but `scriptsize` is not an environment but a switch. Remove `\end{scriptsize}` and replace `\begin{scriptsize}` with `\scriptsize`.

Comment: Regarding the horizontal line: Is there a reason for stretching an otherwise narrow table to be as wide as the textwidth?

Answer (score 4):

Considering @leandriis comment, the table can be formatted as shown below. To my opinion this not so bad design of table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell,   % <--- new
            multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m} % <--- new
    {\multicolumn{#1}{l}{#2}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=-1.2,
                        table-column-width=4em]}}
    \toprule
                    &   \mcc[2]{Title}              \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
                    &   $\alpha$    &   $\beta$     \\
    \midrule               
\mcl[3]{\thead[l]{This is a very long, long, long, long,\\
                             long, long, caption for this panel}}      \\
    \midrule
This is config a    &   1.11        &   2.22        \\
This is config b    &  -1.11        &  -2.22        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
In the case, that you prefer to have table width equal to text width, the use of the `tabularx` may be handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell,   % <--- new
            multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m} % <--- new
    {\multicolumn{#1}{l}{#2}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{2}{S[table-format=-1.2,
                        table-column-width=4em]}}
    \toprule
                    &   \mcc[2]{Title}              \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
                    &   $\alpha$    &   $\beta$     \\
    \midrule               
\mcl[3]{\thead[l]{This is a very long, long, long, long,
                  long, long, caption for this panel}}      \\
    \midrule
This is config a    &   1.11        &   2.22        \\
This is config b    &  -1.11        &  -2.22        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to my proposal.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Title}                                       \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
                                     & $\alpha$                        & $\beta$                       \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{This is a very long, long, long, long, long, long, caption for this panel}} \\ \midrule
This is config a                     & 1.11                            & 2.22                          \\
This is config b                     & -1.11                           & -2.22                         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]